# i used to set proxy for axios node js but not working

Tags: node.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
 const agent = new HttpsProxyAgent('proxy:xxx:xxx:xxx');
    let config = {
        httpsAgent: agent,
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: 'https://x.test.com/login/',
        headers: {  
        'content-type': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        }
    };
    
    axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
               if(response.status == 200){
                   console.log('work');
                   return true;
               }else{
                   console.log('not work');
                   return false;
               }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

purpose is check my proxy is banned or not

in fact proxy is banned must be timeout

but why on axios still work with status = 200

but test on postman with same proxy / endpoint  it's timeout for request this is the desired result.